# WooCommerce function with Jquery and inside it PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want a condition met:     subtotal > 500 && customer is friend to fadeIn a element. code:

```
function customer_type_js(){
        $subtotal = $wc_cart->subtotal;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#customer_type').on('change', function() {
                var customer_type = jQuery('#customer_type').val();
                console.log(customer_type);
                if(customer_type == 'friend'){
                    jQuery('#billing_field').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('.std-checkout-button').fadeOut();
                }
                jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
        });     
        </script>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'customer_type_js');
```

Critiera: If frind is selected, show the billing_field. But I also want another condition. 
If cuustomer_type is friend && $subtotal >500
show woocommerce_eu_vat

```
jQuery('#woocommerce_eu_vat_number').fadeIn();
```

I tried the following setup to no avail:

```
function customer_type_js(){
        $subtotal = $wc_cart->subtotal;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#customer_type').on('change', function() {
                var customer_type = jQuery('#customer_type').val();
                console.log(customer_type);
                if(customer_type == 'friend'){
if($subtotal > 500){
                        jQuery('#woocommerce_eu_vat_number').fadeIn();
}
                    jQuery('#billing_field').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('.std-checkout-button').fadeOut();
                }
                jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
        });     
        </script>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'customer_type_js');
```

Comment: So... what's the question? You're using double quotes, so the `$subtotal` variable is expanded into the actual value. As far as the javascript is concerned, that will read `if(750 > 500) {` for a `$wc_cart->subtotal` value of 750, so this should work. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following hooked function, where you will get now the cart subtotal as `$wc_cart->subtotal` doesn't output anything in this hook because `$wc_cart` argument doesn't exit:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script', 30, 1 );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script( $checkout ) {
    $subtotal = (float) WC()->cart->subtotal;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            var a = '#customer_type'
                b = <?php echo $subtotal; ?>;
            $(a).on( 'change', function() {
                var c = $(this).val(),
                    d = '#woocommerce_eu_vat_number',
                    e = '#billing_field',
                    f = '.std-checkout-button';
                console.log(c);
                if( c == 'friend' && b >= 500){
                    $(d).fadeIn();
                    $(e).fadeIn();
                    $(f).fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $(d).fadeOut();
                    $(e).fadeOut();
                    $(f).fadeIn();
                }
                $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

> You can also try to replace `WC()->cart->subtotal` by `WC()->cart->cart_contents_total` which is the non discounted cart item subtotal excluding vat

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one. Is the WC()->cart->subtotal exluding shipping and tax? Or do I need to add a - $cart_object->shipping_tax_total;?

Answer (score 0):

First of all move all js in another file. It should be called only on `jQuery('#customer_type').on('change')` event, better will be `jQuery('#customer_type').change(function(){ ... });`

About hook - you can draw something without js using, after you can trigger this event using jquery listener.

Will be better something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', function() {
    if (something) {
         if (anotherOne) {
            echo 'jQuery("#anotherEl").fadeIn()';
            return;
         }

         echo 'jQuery("#woocommerce_eu_vat_number").fadeIn()';
    }
});
```

or display element with any id and try to trigger this. Also you can't use php code in js. It's possible to fill something in js during php generation but it's bad solution. Also don't forget to use return after condition to prevent another actions.